# Conveniently schedule a command to run later?

Tags: bash, command-line, schedule

What's a simple way to run a command, say, 8 hours from now? I can think of this way:

```
nohup bash -c "sleep 28800 ; ./mycommand.sh" &
```

Is there a more "proper" way?

Comment: Is there something wrong with `nohup` + `sleep`? Why is it "improper"?

Comment: FYI. similar Q&A for periodic command execution: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17394356/921859

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You can use the `at` command.  The `at` execute commands at a later time. The `at` utility shall read commands from standard input and group them together as an at-job, to be executed at a later time.

Usually, `at` is installed by default in Ubuntu, but if your release doesn't include it, install via:

```
sudo apt-get install at
```

For more information, options, examples, and others, see the manpage in [`man 1 at`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man1/at.1.html).

Example of a relative time specification (note the space between `+` and the duration):

```
at now + 8 hours -f ~/myscript.sh
```

You can also use convenient shorthands, like `tomorrow` or `noon`, as in

```
echo "tweet fore" | at teatime
```

**Note:** This will run the command to the left of the pipe *immediately* - and its output (which is piped to `at`) will be run by `at` at the scheduled time. So, the above command schedules `tweet fore` to be run at teatime.

The example also demonstrates how you can pipe actions into `at`.  `at -c` is the way you can examine scheduled actions, which you can conveniently list with their number, as with:

```
at -c 3
```

Comment: In addition, there is `at 8:00` to run the command at an absolute time, and `batch` for "when it looks like the computer is idle"

Comment: In case anyone was wondering, `teatime` is at 4pm. For some reasons it's not mentioned in http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/at.1posix.html but it is in `man at` and here http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man1/at.1.html.

Comment: Wow, `batch` looks like a really useful command (although its mode of operation is weird - no arguments.)

Comment: Maybe we can mention that "at" utility is not installed by default and if anyone else want to get it simply install the "at" package? Edit: Anyway, i simply edited the answer (also fixed the manpage link).

Comment: One nuisance I've discovered with `at` is its lowest resolution is 1 minute. You can schedule `now` or `+1 minute` but nothing between. Can be a bit annoying for trying to just fork a job.

Comment: Can I set the email address to which emails get sent?

Comment: Yes you can.  Take a look at [this](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_at.htm).

Comment: I believe this solution only works if the "command" is a shell script.

Comment: at is capable of describing time in a bunch of different ways ' x| at 4am tomorrow' can be useful.

Comment: How to control the pending commands? See the list? Cancel a command? The documentation is so lacking :(

Comment: http://www.brunolinux.com/02-The_Terminal/The_at_Command.html

Comment: about the whole piping-into-at running now instead of later issue, `echo "/command/to/run" | at teatime` produces the desired outcome

Comment: `at` is very limited because it runs the command only in `sh` so none of your bash aliases or bash functions will work.

Comment: how can i specify the command directly instead of the file?

Comment: Just an addition, on the Mac (perhaps on BSD as well), the syntax is ```at -f <file> <time>```. File first, then time.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, you can set a cron job.

For example if now the time is 14:39:00 and today is friday, 30 august, you can add the following cron job (to be executed after 8 hours) in your crontab file using `crontab -e` command:

```
39 22 30 8 5  /path/to/mycommand.sh
```

More about:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: Ok, yes, I should have mentioned I know about Cron jobs. This is even messier because then it sits around in the crontab indefinitely, right?

Comment: @SteveBennett As in my example, no: 5 means friday, 8 means august, 30, means today.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu: with cron, careful that it could fire again in a few years (when there is another 30th of August occuring on a friday) ...

Comment: @OlivierDulac The current version of Ubuntu will be probably EOF at  that time (30 august 2019) :)

Comment: This is a clever hack.  However 'at' is a much better way.  What would happen if the computer was turned off at 14:39?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu yes, but the crontab itself doesn't get cleared does it? It's just messy.

Comment: @SteveBennett I agree. `cron` is an overkill for a one-off run.

Comment: Err that's still not my point. My point is that the text you entered will (I think) literally still be sitting in your crontab after the event, creating another cleanup task for you.

Comment: @SteveBennett Yes, you are correct. The command will remain in your `crontab` until you remove it. A year later, when you have forgotten who put it there and why, you will be left scratching your head wondering what to do with the command.

Comment: Entering a comment into crontab explaining the purpose of the command would reduce the amount of head scratching.  I put a blank line at the end of my crontab, then add "#Description of my command" followed by the crontab entry for the command.  I do think the correct answer to the original poster is to use "at" instead of a crontab entry.

Comment: In most commercial environments, setting up cron jobs require admin privileges. Most programmers would skip this step (interacting with people). They would rather write their own custom schedulers,

Answer (score 14):

Use the Gnome-based GUI for `cron`, `at`, and the like:

The introduction of the [CronHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) suggests using the `gnome-schedule` gui, which is much nicer than typing all the garbage into the terminal (esp. for "average" Ubuntu users who are not "power" *nix/bsd users.)

Run it by using the Unity Dash (or other applications menu) to look for **Scheduled Tasks** or running `gnome-schedule`.

> On Gnome-based Ubuntu systems Gnome Scheduled tasks tool (from the gnome-schedule 
>   package) in Applications --> System Tools provides a graphical interface with prompting 
>   for using Cron. The project website is at http://gnome-schedule.sourceforge.net/; the
>   software is installable from the Software Center or by typing
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install gnome-schedule
> ```
>
> in a terminal.

Using `gnome-schedule`, for a script in your home directory, a new "at" command would be set up using this type of window:

[image]

Comment: gnome-schedule doesn't seem to exist for Ubuntu 21.04

Answer (score 12):

Check the output of `date` in a loop. This is a quick and dirty way to do this, like if you can't use `at`, `cron`, or other tools.

Say you want your script to run at noon:

```
until [[ $(date +%H:%M) == 12:00 ]]; do
    sleep 30
done
./mycommand.sh
```

Say you want it to run tomorrow at noon (today is Nov 24 for me):

```
until [[ $(date +%d_%H:%M) == "25_12:00" ]]; do 
    sleep 30
done
./mycommand.sh
```

---

Previously, this answer recommended regex, which has some pitfalls, like a lot of special characters. As well it recommended matching against the whole date string, which is more error-prone since it's locale-dependent. For example, I use some French locale formats since I live in Quebec, so if I forget about that and write `until [[ $(date) == "25 12:00" ]]`, it will never match because the French ordering is "day month year, time" instead of the English "month day time year".

Comment: To the two people who've upvoted this answer, please use `at`, `cron`, or any other real scheduler application. Task scheduling is hard, and not a wheel you should reinvent.

Comment: @dimo414 What's wrong with my method?

Comment: At a minimum, it's busy-waiting, which is wasteful. Worse, it's not guaranteed to be correct; it's perfectly possible (if unlikely) for the conditional to be missed. Basing your scheduler on regular expressions is also highly error-prone. It might work *well-enough*, but has no advantages over `at`.

Comment: Another reason to use `at` is because its jobs will survive a reboot.

Comment: My server doesn't have `at` installed and I'm a user without sudo. I think this alternative is better. @dimo414

Comment: @Eli your server certainly does have `cron` or another task scheduling tool.

Comment: This'll do the trick. I have no sudo and can't access cron or at either. I'm not staying up any later to schedule an experiment that I want run by tomorrow. I'll bet there are better ways to do this, but they're all eating into my sleep schedule at this point.

Comment: I upvote this solution because I agree with @yihui.dev and this solution is not *fully* busy-waiting as `sleep 30` shows(it is actually polling timer with semi-waiting).  I know `cron(8)` & `at(1)`  should be better if I can use it, but this solution could be better in some situations (e.g.  need to merge the output to /proc/1/fd/1, or some auditing system wrongly detect crond as security issue  -- in my case;-( )

Answer (score 3):

If you are running bash on a mac you will run into some difficulties using the `at` program. In that case you can improve on your original proposed solution of,

```
nohup bash -c "sleep 28800 ; ./mycommand.sh" &
```

with this,

```
nohup bash -c "sleep $(echo '8 * 60 * 60' | bc) ; ./mycommand.sh" &
```

which is a more readable form of how long you want to wait. In this example `8` is the number of hours you want to wait before running your script `mycommand.sh`.

Comment: Why you have chosen to use bc instead of shell arithmetic expansion? i.e. nohup bash -c "sleep $((8*60*60)) ; ./mycommand.sh" &

Answer (score 0):

In order to install `gnome-schedule` on Ubuntu 21.04 you can do

```
$ sudo snap install gnome-schedule --edge --jailmode
```