# Why are there different versions of a man page in the Ubuntu Manpage Repository?

Tags: manpage

Why are there two or more different versions of a manpage in http://manpages.ubuntu.com

For example, looking at the manpage of [`at`](https://askubuntu.com/a/339301/8698), you can find two, one that is provided by the `manpages-posix` package <sup>[[ref]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/at.1posix.html)</sup>. And another that is provided by the `at` package itself <sup>[[ref]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/at.1.html)</sup>.
The same is valid for other packages as well like [ls.1](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/ls.1.html) and [ls.1posix](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/ls.1posix.html) and [ls.1plan9](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/ls.1plan9.html).

What I understood from a quick search is that *posix* means that it's a standard specified by IEEE to maintain compatibility between different OS <sup>[[ref]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)</sup>.

So does Ubuntu has its own implementation of a program?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[POSIX stipulates a number of commands are available](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) (see the Shell & Utilities volume) and that they work in a certain way. Here are those commands:

> `admin` `alias` `ar` `asa` `at` `awk` `basename` `batch` `bc` `bg` `break` `c99` `cal` `cat` `cd` `cflow` `chgrp` `chmod` `chown` `cksum` `cmp` `colon` `comm` `command` `compress` `continue` `cp` `crontab` `csplit` `ctags` `cut` `cxref` `date` `dd` `delta` `df` `diff` `dirname` `dot` `du` `echo` `ed` `env` `eval` `ex` `exec` `exit` `expand` `export` `expr` `false` `fc` `fg` `file` `find` `fold` `fort77` `fuser` `gencat` `get` `getconf` `getopts` `grep` `hash` `head` `iconv` `id` `ipcrm` `ipcs` `jobs` `join` `kill` `lex` `link` `ln` `locale` `localedef` `logger` `logname` `lp` `ls` `m4` `mailx` `make` `man` `mesg` `mkdir` `mkfifo` `more` `mv` `newgrp` `nice` `nl` `nm` `nohup` `od` `paste` `patch` `pathchk` `pax` `pr` `printf` `prs` `ps` `pwd` `qalter` `qdel` `qhold` `qmove` `qmsg` `qrerun` `qrls` `qselect` `qsig` `qstat` `qsub` `read` `readonly` `renice` `return` `rm` `rmdel` `rmdir` `sact` `sccs` `sed` `set` `sh` `shift` `sleep` `sort` `split` `strings` `strip` `stty` `tabs` `tail` `talk` `tee` `test` `time` `times` `touch` `tput` `tr` `trap` `true` `tsort` `tty` `type` `ulimit` `umask` `unalias` `uname` `uncompress` `unexpand` `unget` `uniq` `unlink` `unset` `uucp` `uudecode` `uuencode` `uustat` `uux` `val` `vi` `wait` `wc` `what` `who` `write` `xargs` `yacc` `zcat`

GNU coreutils (what GNU/Linux distributions ship) contains all these commands but they have developed away from the standard POSIX base over time. Some offer better features. Some work in slightly different ways. These coretils versions are what the standard `man` pages cater for.

But it is still desirable to write scripts that work on many platforms. For example, if you tried to use extended coreutil functionality of `grep` on OSX, you'd run into syntax errors. And this is why knowing how the POSIX version works is desirable. Install `manpages-posix` and you know everything.

It's also essential to know this stuff if you're planning on improving GNU coreutils.

Plan9 is different yet again. It was never designed to be POSIX compatible. It strives for an amount of POSIX compatibility through a emulation layer and the man pages for it are again, there as documentation to let you know what you can use.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to view a certain version of the man page with the `man` program? See [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=at) and the pages have the same name and section so how would I open a certain page?

Comment: @minerz029 You need to specify the section explicitly. They use the same sections as traditional manpages but with `posix` suffixed on. For example: `man 1posix ls`

Answer (score 3):

## More Uses of POSIX Manpages

Besides what Oli said about writing portable scripts (and [hacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker_%28programmer_subculture%29) on [coreutils](https://gnu.org/software/coreutils/)), there are two other situations where the POSIX manual pages may come in handy:

#### 1. You've configured (more) POSIX-compliant behavior.

If you set the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable (to anything, it can even be blank), many GNU utilities and some other programs will behave in the fashion specified by POSIX, even when the developers saw no reason users would likely want this behavior.

This doesn't make your system behave like a truely POSIX-compliant OS. The Linux kernel, GNU libc, and many userlands tools are all deliberately designed to be POSIX-compliant *only when doing so is more helpful than harmful*. This is one of the reasons GNU/Linux systems like Ubuntu are widely considered not to be Unix systems.

The behavior of `ls` is affected by [a great many things](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103913/difference-between-dir-and-ls-terminal-commands), but is *not* affected by whether or not `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is set. (You can verify this by checking the source code in, say, 13.04: [`ls-ls.c`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/raring/coreutils/raring/view/head:/src/ls-ls.c), [`ls.h`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/raring/coreutils/raring/view/head:/src/ls.h), and [`ls.c`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/raring/coreutils/raring/view/head:/src/ls.c) make no reference to that environment variable.)

But some other utilities are affected. For example, the `df` utility prints disk usage information for all mounted devices. Normally, Ubuntu's `df` (privided by GNU coreutils) shows this in 1 kilobyte blocks. With `POSIXLY_CORRECT` set, it shows it in 512 B (i.e., half-kilobyte) blocks. That behavior is required by the POSIX standard, but [probably not useful to most users](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Non_002dGNU-Standards), so it is not the default.

```
ek@Kip:~$ df
Filesystem      1K-blocks       Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda8        15481840   11816640   2878768  81% /
udev              1020748         12   1020736   1% /dev
tmpfs              412840       5156    407684   2% /run
none                 5120          0      5120   0% /run/lock
none              1032100        240   1031860   1% /run/shm
none               102400         32    102368   1% /run/user
/dev/sda6          245679     159043     73529  69% /boot
/dev/sda9        31458256   10024972  19835284  34% /home
/dev/sdd1      1922859824 1687175656 138008496  93% /media/ek/Noether
/dev/sdc1      1922859824 1700447368 124736784  94% /media/ek/Baker
/dev/sdb1      1922859824 1782944724  42239428  98% /media/ek/Spinoza

ek@Kip:~$ POSIXLY_CORRECT= df
Filesystem     512B-blocks       Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda8         30963680   23573440   5817376  81% /
udev               2041496         24   2041472   1% /dev
tmpfs               825680      10312    815368   2% /run
none                 10240          0     10240   0% /run/lock
none               2064200        480   2063720   1% /run/shm
none                204800         64    204736   1% /run/user
/dev/sda6           491358     318086    147058  69% /boot
/dev/sda9         62916512   20049944  39670568  34% /home
/dev/sdd1       3845719648 3374351312 276016992  93% /media/ek/Noether
/dev/sdc1       3845719648 3400894736 249473568  94% /media/ek/Baker
/dev/sdb1       3845719648 3565889448  84478856  98% /media/ek/Spinoza
```

#### 2. There's no "regular" manpage for the command/topic you're interested in.

Sometimes the POSIX manual page is the only one available. For example, the `cd` command is a [shell builtin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_builtin) only. It's provided by different shells and behaves a little bit differently from shell to shell (in that different shells sometimes make `cd` accept different [command-line options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_option#Command-line_option)).

The default interactive shell in Ubuntu is `bash` and you *can* get information about `cd` in [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man1/bash.1.html). But if you want a manual page just for `cd`, well, there's no `cd` executable (no single globally usable, shell-independent `cd` command).

But the `cd` command is a required part of the POSIX standard--shells must implement it, and the POSIX standard "knows" about what it requires. So [a POSIX manpage for `cd` is possible, and exists.](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man1/cd.1posix.html)

Searching for `cd` on [manpages.ubuntu.com](http://manpages.ubuntu.com) [shows the POSIX manual page and two others](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=cd&op=&cx=003883529982892832976:5zl6o8w6f0s&cof=FORID:9&ie=UTF-8&siteurl=manpages.ubuntu.com/&ref=&ss=68j4624j2). This is another kind of example of multiple manual pages with the same name, by the way. What are the others? [One](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man3/cd.3tcl.html) is the `cd` command *in the language [Tcl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl)*. [The other](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man4/cd.4freebsd.html) is a CD-ROM driver in the FreeBSD operating system. Manual pages for FreeBSD are sometimes helpful to Ubuntu users, so a whole collection of them can be installed, including [`man 4 cd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man4/cd.4freebsd.html) (not one of the FreeBSD manual pages most likely to be helpful to Ubuntu users not also using FreeBSD).

## Why Plan 9?

You might be wondering why there are [Plan 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_9_from_Bell_Labs) manual pages in Ubuntu at all. After all, unlike Ubuntu (and many other OSes such as FreeBSD), Plan 9 is not even a [Unix-*style*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like) operating system, though as Oli says there are some similarities.

The reason for this is that *the Plan 9 userland tools* (the basic set of tools corresponding very roughly to coreutils) have been ported to Unix-like systems, so they can be run on OSes such as Ubuntu. They, and their manual pages, are provided by the [`9base`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/9base) package.

Some (not all) of the Plan 9 tools available for Ubuntu have the same name as Ubuntu tools, and perform the same or similar functions.

One of the reasons for having the Plan 9 tools on Ubuntu is that some of them don't correspond directly to any Ubuntu tool (but may still need the tools that do, for interoperability).

Another reason is to support software that depends on Plan 9 tools. For example, the window manager [wmii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wmii) used to be packaged for Ubuntu (and available in official Ubuntu software sources); this [`wmii2`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/wmii2) package depended on `9base`.