# Will I find only GNU command line tools in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, gnu

A couple well known command line tools exist in several versions depending on
the Unix flavor (like sed, find, ld).

I was wondering which versions are available in Ubuntu (I assume GNU for all but I'd like to confirm that)?

Comment: I think you'll need to narrow this down. The different tools have different differences. For example, the `-i` option to `sed` works differently on GNU and BSD sed, certain options of `find` (`-delete` and `-not` for example) are not available in non-GNU versions etc. It isn't possible to answer this in a general way, only by listing differences of _specific_ programs. As for 2, to my knowledge _all_ GNU/Linux distributions will have the GNU tools, yes.

Comment: @terdon, thanks for your quick reply, actually I was more interested in the confirmation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways of interpreting your question so I'll be explicit in my answers.

#### Are all command line applications in Ubuntu GNU projects?

Of course not, you can install whatever you like and there are many things that are part of Ubuntu or Debian directly that aren't upstream.

#### What about the most the command-line applications that ship with Ubuntu?

`coreutils` makes up a vast swathe of these (and this is a GNU project — it's what the GNU in GNU/Linux represents) but in order to be POSIX compliant, a system needs more than just `coreutils`.

Just in case you're wondering what `coreutils` covers, here's its package description:

```
 This package contains the basic file, shell and text manipulation
 utilities which are expected to exist on every operating system.

 Specifically, this package includes: arch base64 basename cat chcon chgrp
 chmod chown chroot cksum comm cp csplit cut date dd df dir dircolors
 dirname du echo env expand expr factor false flock fmt fold groups head
 hostid id install join link ln logname ls md5sum mkdir mkfifo mknod mktemp
 mv nice nl nohup nproc od paste pathchk pinky pr printenv printf ptx pwd
 readlink rm rmdir runcon sha*sum seq shred sleep sort split stat stty sum
 sync tac tail tee test timeout touch tr true truncate tsort tty uname
 unexpand uniq unlink users vdir wc who whoami yes
```

#### So are all POSIX commands GNU?

No. While Ubuntu does use GNU, it relies on a lot of non-GNU projects for its POSIX compliance.

I've covered [which commands are POSIX before](https://askubuntu.com/a/342106/449) so with that list, we can quickly generate a list of packages and then grab all the project Homepage URLs from those packages. Even without visiting the URLs you can see that they're not GNU (some are even overtly nonGNU).

```
$ apt-cache show $(for c in "admin alias ar asa at awk basename batch bc bg break c99 cal cat cd cflow chgrp chmod chown cksum cmp colon comm command compress continue cp crontab csplit ctags cut cxref date dd delta df diff dirname dot du echo ed env eval ex exec exit expand export expr false fc fg file find fold fort77 fuser gencat get getconf getopts grep hash head iconv id ipcrm ipcs jobs join kill lex link ln locale localedef logger logname lp ls m4 mailx make man mesg mkdir mkfifo more mv newgrp nice nl nm nohup od paste patch pathchk pax pr printf prs ps pwd qalter qdel qhold qmove qmsg qrerun qrls qselect qsig qstat qsub read readonly renice return rm rmdel rmdir sact sccs sed set sh shift sleep sort split strings strip stty tabs tail talk tee test time times touch tput tr trap true tsort tty type ulimit umask unalias uname uncompress unexpand unget uniq unlink unset uucp uudecode uuencode uustat uux val vi wait wc what who write xargs yacc zcat"; do dpkg -S $(readlink -f $(which $c)); done | awk -F: '{print $1}' | sort -u) | awk '/Package|Homepage/'

Package: at
Package: bc
Homepage: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bc/
Package: binutils
Package: bison
Homepage: http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/
Package: bsdmainutils
Package: bsdutils
Homepage: http://userweb.kernel.org/~kzak/util-linux/
Package: coreutils
Homepage: http://gnu.org/software/coreutils
Package: cron
Homepage: http://ftp.isc.org/isc/cron/
Package: cups-client
Homepage: http://www.cups.org
Package: dash
Homepage: http://gondor.apana.org.au/~herbert/dash/
Package: diffutils
Homepage: http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/
Package: ed
Homepage: http://www.gnu.org/software/ed/
Package: file
Homepage: http://www.darwinsys.com/file/
Package: findutils
Homepage: http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/findutils/
Package: flex
Homepage: http://flex.sf.net/
Package: gawk
Homepage: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/
Package: gcc
Package: graphviz
Homepage: http://www.graphviz.org/
Package: grep
Homepage: http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/
Package: gzip
Package: heirloom-mailx
Homepage: http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx.html
Package: libc-bin
Homepage: http://www.eglibc.org
Package: libc-dev-bin
Homepage: http://www.eglibc.org
Package: login
Homepage: http://pkg-shadow.alioth.debian.org/
Package: m4
Homepage: http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/
Package: make
Homepage: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/
Package: man-db
Homepage: http://man-db.nongnu.org/
Package: ncurses-bin
Homepage: http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/
Package: patch
Package: pax
Package: procps
Homepage: http://gitorious.org/procps
Package: psmisc
Homepage: http://psmisc.sf.net/
Package: sed
Homepage: http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/
Package: sharutils
Homepage: http://www.gnu.org/software/sharutils/
Package: sysvinit-utils
Homepage: http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/sysvinit
Package: time
Homepage: http://www.gnu.org/software/time
Package: util-linux
Homepage: http://userweb.kernel.org/~kzak/util-linux/
Package: vim-tiny
Homepage: http://www.vim.org/
```

Comment: Thanks for the link related to POSIX commands, very instructive (and for this complete answer).

Answer (score 2):

You can see User-land "GNU" from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29)- .

[image: wikipedia]

So, GNU commands are available for Ubuntu. To see available commands, see [**List of GNU Packages**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GNU_packages).

And for particular command (Ex : [find](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find)): [findutils from **GNU Project**](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/)

Answer (score 1):

Almost all Unix commands exist with different versions depending on the OS used.

There are significant differences, usually GNU extensions to the POSIX standard.

On Ubuntu, you can expect the GNU version to be the standard for most of these commands, but not necessarily all.

The most obvious example is `/bin/sh` which is a link to `dash` on Ubuntu and not any more `bash` like it used to be.

While `bash` is part of the GNU project, `dash` comes from originally from a netBSD one.

Comment: That would have been my assumption too but [this isn't actually true](http://askubuntu.com/a/456875/449). There are multiple POSIX-specified applications used (by default in Ubuntu) that aren't GNU variants.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, GNU implementations of Unix tools are usually richer in available options. However, probably there are exceptions.
Sometimes there are also differences in default behavior. For example, GNU "find" run without a directory implicitely assumes running in the current directory. On SunOS, this is incorrect and you have to type "find ." to get the same result.