# How to access the manpage fo a flatpak application?

Tags: command-line, manpage, flatpak

Where does one find the manpage of a flatpak application?

For example, I know that Thunderbird usually has a manpage. However, I have tried the following two commands to no avail.

```sh
[user ~]$ man thunderbird
No manual entry for thunderbird

[user ~]$ flatpak run --command="bash" org.mozilla.Thunderbird
[ org.mozilla.Thunderbird ~]$ man thunderbird
bash: man: command not found
```

Note: There is a [similar question on askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342102/why-are-there-different-versions-of-a-man-page-in-the-ubuntu-manpage-repository), however, it is related to a specific software, and the answer pertains to that software only.

Comment: `man` pages are installed when you install an application (*for default deb packages*).  Those pages will only exist in other formats (such as *flatpak*) IF they are created/packaged with the pages... ie. if the creator of the flatpak didn't package or allow for it; it won't work.  Your `man thunderbird` example failed I suspect due to $PATH for the flatpak shell & is unrelated; and I don't see your connection with the other question which to me applies as it was generic (alas didn't apply to containerized packages).  This is my opinion only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flatpaks were primarily developed for graphical user applications. As such, there does not appear to be standard provisions to integrate with the `man` system, so a flatpak typically will not install a local man page.