# Create multiple shell aliases at once

Tags: command-line, alias

I want to insert into alias different possible variants of spelling, for example, `cat` command. Can I do it using some symbol for 'or' or should it be on a new line?

```
alias at|cart|cst '/bin/cat'
```

Comment: Reminds me of one alias I have: `alias kk='ll'`

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `at` as an alias for `cat`. There's an actual command `at` for scheduling stuff: https://askubuntu.com/a/339301/295286

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The help for `alias` indicates that it can assign multiple aliases at once:

```
alias: alias [-p] [name[=value] ... ]
    Define or display aliases.

    Without arguments, `alias' prints the list of aliases in the reusable
    form `alias NAME=VALUE' on standard output.

    Otherwise, an alias is defined for each NAME whose VALUE is given.
    A trailing space in VALUE causes the next word to be checked for
    alias substitution when the alias is expanded.
```

So you can use brace expansion to generate the `name=value` pairs:

```
alias {at,cart,cst}='/bin/cat'
```

So:

```
$ alias {at,cart,cst}='/bin/cat'
$ type at cart cst
at is aliased to `/bin/cat'
cart is aliased to `/bin/cat'
cst is aliased to `/bin/cat'
```

That said, look in to zsh, which has [built-in typo correction](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_16.html) (which wouldn't help for `at`, but it would help for the others):

> ```
> % setopt correct
> % sl
> zsh: correct `sl' to `ls' [nyae]? y
> % setopt correctall
> % ls x.v11r4
> zsh: correct `x.v11r4' to `X.V11R4' [nyae]? n
> /usr/princton/src/x.v11r4 not found
> % ls /etc/paswd
> zsh: correct to `/etc/paswd' to `/etc/passwd' [nyae]? y
> /etc/passwd
> ```
>
> If you press `y` when the shell asks you if you want to correct a
>   word, it will be corrected. If you press `n`, it will be left alone.
>   Pressing `a` aborts the command, and pressing `e` brings the line up
>   for editing again, in case you agree the word is spelled wrong but you
>   don't like the correction.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you can assign multiple aliases at once.
But you could loop through a list like this:

```bsh
for a in cart xat vat xst cst vst dog; do alias "$a"='/bin/cat'; done
```

Make sure that the aliases are not already in use by other programs (like  `at` in your example).

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works well. I have one of my linux machines with tsch as default. I tried this: foreach x ( cst cart );alias $x='/bin/cat';end.

Comment: @JosefKlimuk: Sounds like it would be worth its own answer. :-)

Comment: @David Foerster, Should I ask it as independent question?

Comment: @JosefKlimuk: No. I mean that you should write a proper answer to *this question* based on your previous comment.