# Can I run a scheduled task once?

Tags: command-line, server, schedule

This might be a duplicate post but couldn't find one.

I'm looking for a way to run a shell script once at a specific time.

Like run it once at 16:00 then remove from queue. `crontab` has no setting for this as I can find since it runs on repeat and not like fire and forget kind I'm looking for.

Anyone got a good suggestion? I want it to be run on Ubuntu 18.04  server version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `cron` but `at`:

```
echo 'mycommand' | at 16:00
```

or

```
at 16:00 -f some_script.sh
```

[See this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339298/conveniently-schedule-a-command-to-run-later)