# Command-Line Alarm Clock for Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation

software recommendation needed! I'm looking for an alarm clock to use on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine, with a command-line interface to enable me to set alarms from the command line. This is because in my workflow I often have to set many alarms a day, usually only about an hour out. Since I do this so often it's a pain to mess with a GUI all the time.

I tried GNOME clocks of course, but seems it has no command-line interface.

Can anyone recommend anything like what I'm looking for? Not too picky, just need it to do its job.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`at` command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339298/conveniently-schedule-a-command-to-run-later) (not installed by default on Ubuntu 20.04). It allows you to execute a command at a specific time. You could for example have a Zenity dialog pop up to serve as an alarm.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`sleep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/sleep.1.html) command, which comes preinstalled on Ubuntu, to run a command after the specified amount of time as:

```
sleep NUMBER[SUFFIX] && command
```

From `man sleep`:

> ```
> DESCRIPTION
>        Pause for NUMBER seconds.  SUFFIX may be 's' for seconds (the default), 'm'
>        for minutes, 'h' for hours or 'd' for days.  Unlike most implementations
>        that require NUMBER be an integer, here NUMBER may be an arbitrary floating
>        point number.  Given two or more arguments, pause for the amount of time
>        specified by the sum of their values.
> ```

For example, you may run:

```
sleep 3h 5m 25s && mpv file
```

to open `file` with the `mpv` media player after 3 hours, 5 minutes and 25 seconds.

---

`sleep` is perfectly usable and straightforward for running commands *after* a certain amount of time, however `at` is better for running a command *at* (no surprise here) a specified time.

Nevertheless, a similar behavior can be implemented with `sleep`. Here is an example script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
alarm_time=$1
command=$2

# convert alarm_time and current_time to seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
# and calculate their difference
alarm_time=$(date -d "$alarm_time" +"%s")
current_time=$(date +"%s")
diff=$(( $alarm_time - $current_time ))

# convert the time difference to hours
sleep_time=$(echo "scale=5; $diff/3600" | bc)

# run the command at the specified time
sleep "$sleep_time"h && $command
```

After saving it as `alarm.sh` (choose your preferred name) and making it executable, you can run it as:

```
/path/to/alarm.sh time command
```

You can add the script to your path for easier access, if you wish, and you can also hard code the command to run by replacing `$2` with the command you want to run.

Comment: Difficult to have that fire at 15:00 sharply, though.

Comment: @vanadium Agree. The advantage of `sleep` is that it is preinstalled and is perfectly usable and straightforward for running commands after a certain amount of time. To run a command at a specified time, it is pretty easy to implement a script that uses `sleep`. Of course it would be a waste of time, since `at` already does that.

Comment: Interesting, but that is not reflected in your answer. If you could elaborate how you can use sleep to do something at a specified time, then it would be OK. b.t.w. `at` is a pretty standard GNU utility that happens not to be installed anymore in current Ubuntu versions.

Comment: @vanadium I added an example script to the answer. Please check it out.

Comment: Indeed, calculating the time it takes to reach the target time is a trick. So one can survive with Ubuntu on an island where installing `at` is not an option :-)

Comment: I know this may sound like a new question, but related to this: is there an easy way to play a system sound as alarm sound instead of having to open a media player and play an .mp3 or similar file?

Comment: @Andyc This should really be a new question, so please ask one. You can refer to this thread to provide context if needed. Thanks!