# How can I schedule one(!) reboot?

Tags: 20.04, schedule

Say I want my machine to reboot tomorrow at 02:00 am. And not again later, just that one time tomorrow morning. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `shutdown -r` with `TIME` option:

```
$ shutdown -r 02:00
Shutdown scheduled for Fri 2022-04-22 02:00:00 CEST, use 'shutdown -c' to cancel.
```

From `man shutdown`:

```
SYNOPSIS  
  shutdown [OPTIONS...] [TIME] [WALL...]

DESCRIPTION  
  [...]
  The time string may either be in the format "hh:mm" [...] specified in 24h clock format.
  Alternatively it may be in the syntax "+m" referring to the specified number of minutes m from now.

OPTIONS  
  [...]  
  -r, --reboot
          Reboot the machine
```

---

Alternatively you can [use `at`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339298/conveniently-schedule-a-command-to-run-later) to schedule a program execution:

```
$ echo "reboot -f" | at 02:00
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 1 at Fri Apr 22 02:00:00 2022
```

See list of scheduled commands along with its `id` using `atq`, remove from list with `atrm <id>`.

(may need to install `sudo apt install at`).

---

**Note**: `at` has the benefit that the schedule survives reboots, while the scheduled `shutdown` will be canceled when rebooting before `02:00`.